# Eigenvalues of a special matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $T>2$ is an integer, the matrix I am dealing with has the form of \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{T} & \frac{1}{T} & \frac{1}{T} & \cdots  & \frac{1}{T} \\ 
\frac{1}{T} & \frac{1}{T-1} & \frac{1}{T-1} & \cdots \  & \frac{1}{T-1} \\ 
\frac{1}{T} & \frac{1}{T-1} & \frac{1}{T-2} & \cdots \  & \frac{1}{T-2} \\ 
\vdots \  & \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots \  & \vdots  \\ 
\frac{1}{T} & \frac{1}{T-1} & \frac{1}{T-2} & \cdots  &  \frac{1}{2}%
\end{pmatrix}
Is there any way to find the eigenvalues for this matrix for a given $T$? Thanks!

Comment: It should be a $(T-1)\times(T-1)$ matrix for a given $T$.

Comment: One thing sure is $\det(\cdot)=\dfrac{2}{(T!)^2}$

Comment: Did you find out the answer?

Comment: No, but it has been a while